# How to prevent display of specific paragraph types (bundles) on nodes

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, paragraphs

I have a content type with a paragraph field which has many paragraph types available.  For one of these paragraph types, I do not want it displayed in the node because I am displaying it using a view in a different region.  The view works great but I cannot figure out how to prevent the specific paragraph type from displaying on the node. I've tried to removeItem from the render array using various hooks in .theme, but this removes it from the view as well.  I have also tried to remove the paragraph type from the paragraph field in the node template using a loop in twig.  I feel like there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Twig's `without` filter worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_formatter.

Create a view that does what you want using contextual filter of the node id.

Than modify the node display settings to use that view.